# Site stats broken?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Anyone else seeing 0's for all the site stats?

Edit - just noticed the same thing on webapps - must be across all the betas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal -- the stats refresh is every 10 minutes, and sometimes after we deploy the timing is wrong, so the stats may say zero for the first 10 minutes.